# Averaging XY points locations if in close proximity automatically over a large dataset in R

Tags: r, point, merge, xyz, proximity

I have a point dataset (XYZ values) containing a few million points covering a 5km x 5km extent representing maxima locations. However there a great deal of these points which exist in 0.5m of others.

I would like to identify the points which are within 1m of one another and then average the coordinates to create a single point. I have written an R script to perform this task automatically on the XYZ data, see below. The process uses a loop, and operates on one point per iteration.

On large datasets this approach takes a long time to complete due to its iterative-loop nature, can any of you recommend a more efficient approach within R?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

```
##Sample data (17 point subset)
X <- c(671847.25, 671849.25, 671849.25, 671849.75, 671854.75, 671849.25, 671851.25, 
671854.75, 671854.25, 671854.75, 671850.75, 671856.75, 671852.75, 671852.75, 
671854.75, 671856.75, 671854.75)
Y <- c(3984125.75, 3984125.75, 3984125.25, 3984125.25, 3984123.75, 3984123.25, 
3984123.25, 3984123.25, 3984121.75, 3984121.75, 3984120.25, 3984120.25, 3984119.75, 
3984119.25, 3984118.75, 3984118.75, 3984117.25)
Z <- c(10.10000038, 12.31000042, 12.31000042,12.31000042,10.02000046, 11.30000019, 
9.489999771, 10.02000046, 10.11999989, 10.11999989, 10.57999992, 10.11999989, 
9.930000305, 9.930000305, 9.739999771, 10.72000027, 9.409999847) 

maxima.data <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)

##set up empty output df to write new points to
results <- data.frame(x=as.numeric(), y=as.numeric(), z=as.numeric())
results <- rbind(results, c(0,0,0))
colnames(results) <- c("x", "y", "z")

while(nrow(maxima.data) > 0){
##Select first row in df, and perform a subset to identify all points within 1m
#always use first row
max.in.row <- subset(maxima.data, maxima.data[,1] < maxima.data[1,1]+1 & maxima.data[,1] > maxima.data[1,1]-1 &     
maxima.data[,2] < maxima.data[1,2]+1 & maxima.data[,2] > maxima.data[1,2]-1) 

##If more than 1 point/row returned, average the three columns XYZ to produce new 
#point, otherwise the point stays the same and send to new 'results' DF
#And remove the point(s) in the original DF
#
if(nrow(max.in.row) > 1){
    #calculate column averages
    max.mean.row <- c(mean(max.in.row[,1]),mean(max.in.row[,2]),mean(max.in.row[,3]))       
        #select rows in maxima.data to remove
    for(j in 1:nrow(max.in.row)){   #for loop no.1
        row.exclude <- which(maxima.data[,1] == max.in.row[j,1] & maxima.data[,2] == max.in.row[j,2])
        maxima.data <- maxima.data[-row.exclude,]
        rm(row.exclude)
        } #end for loop no.1

    #output
    results <- rbind(results, max.mean.row)
    rm(max.mean.row)

        } else {    #if only one row

    results <- rbind(results, maxima.data[1,])
    maxima.data <- maxima.data[-1,]

    }
    rm(max.in.row)

    }#end while loop

results <- results[-1,] #remove row of zeros
row.names(results) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than "first one encountered" I am not sure what criteria one would use to select a point to retain. It seems quite arbitrary and a point may share multiple neighbors with your distance criteria but would not be retained if not in the correct selection order. This could add serious bias to your mean. It seems that you should calculate your neighbor means first then figure out how to reduce the dimensionality.

This may be a good starting point for you. Here is a way to quickly generate a distance matrix or a Boolean matrix based on your distance threshold. You could write a function, that could be passed to apply, that aggregates observations and then pass the results to tapply to calculate the aggregated means. This is a very R like approach and would speed things up considerably.

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)

d=1  # Distance 
n=10 # Number of observations
maxima <- data.frame(X=runif(n,671847.2,671856.8),Y=runif(n,3984117,3984126),
                     Z=runif(n,9.41,12.31))     
    coordinates(maxima) <- ~X+Y 
      plot(maxima,pch=20)

( dmat <- gDistance(maxima, byid=TRUE) )
( dmat <- gWithinDistance(maxima, byid=TRUE, dist=d) )
```

For reference, here is a function that I wrote for calculating a distance weighted mean, based on a neighbor distance threshold, for each observation.

```
###########################################################################
# PROGRAM: distWeighted.smoothing
# USE: DISTANCE-WEIGHTED SMOOTHING OF POINT VALUES 
# REQUIRES: >= R 3.0, sp, RANN                                          
#                                                                         
# ARGUMENTS:
#      x     OBJECT OF CLASS SpatialPointsDataFrame
#      y     COLUMN TO CALCULATE WEIGHTED MEAN 
#      d     DISTANCE CONSTRAINT        
#      k     MAXIMUM NUMBER OF K-NEAREST NEIGHBORS WITHIN d    
#                                                                         
# EAXMPLE: 
#  require(sp)
#  require(classInt)
#  require(RColorBrewer)
#    data(meuse)                                                   
#      coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y             
#    
#   # CALCULATE DISTANCE WEIGHTED MEAN ON CADMIUM VARIABLE IN MEUSE DATA
#    cadmium.dwm <- distWeighted.smoothing(meuse, "cadmium", k=4, d=500)                
#      meuse@data$cadmium.wm <- cadmium.dwm  
#   
#   # PLOT RESULTS
#   plotclr <- rev(brewer.pal(4, "Spectral"))
#    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#       cuts <- classIntervals(meuse@data$cadmium, n=length(plotclr), style="quantile")
#         colcode <- findColours(cuts, plotclr)
#       plot(meuse, col=colcode, pch=19)
#         title("Cadmium")
#           legend("bottomright", legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), 
#                  fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), bty="n") 
#            box()
#       cuts <- classIntervals(meuse@data$cadmium.wm, n=length(plotclr), style="quantile")
#         colcode <- findColours(cuts, plotclr)
#       plot(meuse, col=colcode, pch=19)
#         title("Cadmium Dist Weighted Mean")
#           legend("bottomright", legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), 
#                  fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), bty="n") 
#            box()
#         
# OUTPUT: 
#      OBJECT OF CLASS VECTOR                 
#
# NOTES:
#
# REFERENCES:
#      Baruch-Mordo, S., J.S. Evans, J. Severson, J. D. Naugle, J. Kiesecker, 
#        J. Maestas, and M.J. Falkowski (2013) Saving sage-grouse from the 
#        trees: A proactive solution to reducing a key threat to a candidate 
#        species Biological Conservation 167:233-241 
#
# CONTACT: 
#     Jeffrey S. Evans 
#     Senior Landscape Ecologist 
#     The Nature Conservancy,
#     Development by Design
#     Affiliate Assistant Professor
#     University of Wyoming,
#     Zoology & Physiology 
#     Laramie, WY
#     (970)672-6766
#     jeffrey_evans@tnc.org
###########################################################################
distWeighted.smoothing <- function(x, y, d, k) {
    if (!require(sp)) stop("sp PACKAGE MISSING")
      if (!require(RANN)) stop("raster PACKAGE MISSING")
        if (!inherits(x, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")) 
            stop(deparse(substitute(x)), " MUST BE A sp SpatialPointsDataFrame OBJECT") 
          if(is.null(y)) stop("y (value) column must be specified")     
            if(!y %in% names(x@data)) stop(deparse(substitute(y)), "does not exists")
              if(!class(x@data[,y]) == "numeric") stop("y must be numeric")             
    ddata <- data.frame(ID=row.names(x), X=coordinates(x)[,1], Y=coordinates(x)[,1])
      nearest <- nn2(ddata, query=ddata, k=k, treetype=c("bd"), 
                     searchtype=c("radius"), radius=d)       
        knn.id <- as.data.frame(nearest$nn.idx)
          names(knn.id) <- paste("NN", seq(1,ncol(knn.id),1),sep="")
            knn.id  <- data.frame(ID=row.names(x@data), knn.id)  
        knn.dist <- as.data.frame(nearest$nn.dists)
          names(knn.dist) <- paste("NND", seq(1,ncol(knn.dist),1),sep="")              
            knn.dist  <- data.frame(ID=row.names(x@data), knn.dist)
              wts <- rev(seq(1,d,1))/d
    v <- as.numeric()
      for(i in 1:dim(knn.id)[1]) {
        knn.sub <- as.numeric(knn.id[i,][2:k])
          lsub <- x[knn.sub,]
        if (dim(lsub)[1] < 2 ) {
           wt=1 
          } else {
          dsub <- as.numeric(knn.dist[i,][2:k])
            dsub[which(knn.sub == 0)] <- 0
          dsub <- dsub[dsub > 0]
           wt <- round(append(dsub, 1, after=0), digits=0)
              wt <- wts[wt]
            }
        wm <- weighted.mean(lsub@data[,y], wt, na.rm=TRUE)
              wm[is.nan(wm)] <- NA
            v <- append(v, wm, after=length(v) ) 
        }  
    return( v )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply. The apply/tapply approach you suggested seems like it could be the answer.

Comment: Another directly relevant question and answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051141/spatial-filtering-by-proximity-in-r